# Можно ли было вернуть количество четных и нечетных чисел в лямбде?

Tags: python, list, lambda

```
nums = [3, 5, 6, 1, 9, 12]

even_nums = list(map(lambda even : even% 2 == 0, nums))
odd_nums = list(map(lambda odd : odd% 2 != 0, nums))
print('Количество четных: ',even_nums.count(True))
print('Количество нечетных: ',odd_nums.count(True))
```

Comment: что означает "вернуть значение"?

Comment: сколько четных и нечетных чисел

Comment: Я не понял вопроса. Чем приведённый код не устраивает?

Comment: Есть ли другой способ подсчета количества четных и нечетных чисел в лямбде, кроме каунта

Comment: Можно и без лямбды `even_nums = sum(1 for i in nums if i % 2 == 0)`

Comment: я знаю, что можно без лямбы, просто задание такое, нужно использовать лямбд

Comment: так и этот каунт считает совсем не в лямбде, а вне ее

Comment: Вот, я и спросил, можно ли сразу в лямбде подсчитать количество четных и нечетных

Comment: Я продолжаю ничего не понимать, но если понимать утверждение «в лямбде подсчитать» максимально буквально... `even_nums, odd_nums = (lambda nums: (len(nums) - (odd := sum(1 for i in nums if i % 2 != 0)), odd))(nums)`

Comment: Ну если с `sum()`, то можно так `sum(map(lambda even: 1 if even % 2 == 0 else 0, nums))`. Хотя я тоже пока не понял условие того, что можно под lambda использовать)

Comment: `even_nums, odd_nums = (lambda l: (sum(not i % 2 for i in l), sum(i % 2 for i in l)))(nums)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я также как и все не уверен, что понял задание правильно, но пусть будет так:

```
nums = [3, 5, 6, 1, 9, 12]

even_nums = sum(map(lambda n: not n % 2, nums))
odd_nums = sum(map(lambda n: n % 2, nums))
print('Количество четных: ', even_nums)
print('Количество нечетных: ', odd_nums)
```

Вывод:

```
Количество четных:  2
Количество нечетных:  4
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот простая реализация

```py
nums = [3, 5, 6, 1, 9, 12]

result = lambda nums: 'chet: {} nechet: {}'.format(sum((num % 2 == 0) for num in nums), sum((num % 2 != 0) for num in nums))

result(nums)
```

На выходе будет `chet: 2 nechet: 4`

Comment: True - считается как 1, False - как 0.